# correcting mirror ghosting effect

Tags: image-processing, preprocessing

I have an application in which I have to process images taken through a mirror. The camera and mirror positions are fixed, and the object is always in the same position with respect to the mirror. The problem is that I get a ghosting effect because the image is also reflected by the transparent surface of the mirror.

I will try to get a first surface mirror for my application, but I wonder if this ghosting effect can be corrected by software. Any hint would be appreciated (a paper, algorithm, anything). I believe this should be possible, since the camera and mirror are both fixed, and the object is always at the same distance from the mirror, but I don't know where to start looking.

Thank you for any hint/advice you can provide.

[image: Here is an image of a grid pattern with the ghosting effect]
[image: another image with the ghosting effect]

Answer (score 1):

We can assume
$g=i(x,y)*f(x,y)+n(x,y)$, where $g$ is the above images, $i$ is the original image , $f$ is a degradation function and $n$ is image noise. If you find $f$ and deconvolve it with $g$, you'll get $i$ plus some noise. Note, simple deconvolution would not work, because the noise ($n$) in the process is amplified. The Wiener filter can used to restore images that have been degraded by a known degradation function.Here I am not sure what is degradation function.
I suggest you read the following material as well:
[Lecture notes of Prof. William Hoff](http://inside.mines.edu/~whoff/courses/EENG510/lectures/22-Deconvolution.pdf)